# Coin-or - using in my project

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, coin-or-clp

I would like to use COIN-OR as a shared library for my own project, do you have any link to create COIN-OR as a shared library and include it in my project including CMakeList demo?

Answer (score 1):

COIN-OR comprises several projects. Which one in particular would you like to use? See https://projects.coin-or.org/CoinBinary for a comprehensive list.

Regarding clp in particular, all binaries may be found here: https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Clp/.

The [clp webpage](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp) has more information, in particular, you can find details on [building and installing](https://projects.coin-or.org/BuildTools/wiki).